# CiviMail auto-save: disable?

Tags: civimail

The auto-save feature when constructing a CiviMail mailing is a nice feature, but has some issues. We've had a few problems where two users have been in the same mailing at the same time, which creates a race condition -- one person makes an edit, which triggers the auto-save; the second person makes an edit, which triggers an auto-save and overwrites the first user's edits. It's very easy to trigger an auto-save -- simply adding or deleting a space will do so.

I suggest we make auto-save optional (have a config option in the CiviMail component settings) and also add a locking mechanism so that a user cannot edit a mailing if someone else is already in it.

Comment: These are good suggestions - but not really questions!